# How do I run the TtsEngine android sample?

Tags: android, service, text-to-speech

How do I run the TtsEngine android sample?
It is available at
http://java.llp2.dcc.ufmg.br/apiminer/docs/resources/samples/TtsEngine/index.html
and, theoretically, comes with the Android sdk.

It is a service without UI.

Answer (score 0):

1. Set the device language to English
2. Menu > Settings > Language and Input > Text-to-speech output; select the Example TTS Engine